# msxml3.dll error '80072ee2' in ASP page - we are using a different Application Pool

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, msxml3

There are lots of questions that ask about the 80072ee2 "The operation timed out" error in msxml3.dll, but most are resolved by moving the requested URL to a different application pool. But, we already do this and are still getting this error on a semi-regular basis.

We're running a Windows 2008 server and IIS7.5 - the website is Classic ASP and the code is:

```
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://www.mysite.co.uk/_search/search.php", false
xmlhttp.send ""
strResponseText = xmlhttp.responseText
set xmlhttp = nothing
```

The folder '_search' is a virtual folder and is set to use a separate application pool from the main site. It is a busy-ish site, and we don't get a timeout every-time it's called... but once you get one, there are often a number of them in succession. We know this is happening because we're logging the 500 errors on the site.

Does anyone have any ideas (please don't suggest re-writing the Classic ASP or PHP - it's not possible at the moment)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks absolutely fine.  Two things you can try though.

First try

```
Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

This may not make any difference, but you're msxml6.dll - which is present on IIS7 - rather than the older msxml3.dll

Second, if you have Remote desktop access, see what happens when you try to access http://www.mysite.co.uk/_search/search.php from the server's own copy of IE.  I've encountered situations where you can't see a site the server hosts itself through the external URL and you have to use localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks John - we can see the search.php from the local box (as mentioned, the code works most of the time), but we're trying the "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"... will post results here...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new site with the same physical path domain name etc but different port number (like 81)
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://www.mysite.co.uk:81/_search/search.php", false